# How to change color , background and height of the particle background in react-tsparticles?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-particles-js

How to change color and background in react-tsparticles ? This is my *particle-config.js*

```
  const particlesConfig = {
  background: {
    color: {
      value: "#232741",
    },

    position: "50% 50%",
    repeat: "no-repeat",
    size: "20%",
  },
  fullScreen: {
    zIndex: 1,
  },
  interactivity: {
    events: {
      onClick: {
        enable: true,
        mode: "repulse",
      },
      onHover: {
        enable: true,
        mode: "bubble",
      },
    },
    modes: {
      bubble: {
        distance: 250,
        duration: 2,
        opacity: 0,
        size: 0,
      },
      grab: {
        distance: 400,
      },
      repulse: {
        distance: 400,
      },
    },
  },
  particles: {
    color: {
      value: "#ffffff",
    },
    links: {
      color: {
        value: "#ffffff",
      },
      distance: 150,
      opacity: 0.4,
    },
    move: {
      attract: {
        rotate: {
          x: 600,
          y: 600,
        },
      },
      enable: true,
      outModes: {
        bottom: "out",
        left: "out",
        right: "out",
        top: "out",
      },
      random: true,
      speed: 1,
    },
    number: {
      density: {
        enable: true,
      },
      value: 160,
    },
    opacity: {
      random: {
        enable: true,
      },
      value: {
        min: 0,
        max: 1,
      },
      animation: {
        enable: true,
        speed: 1,
        minimumValue: 0,
      },
    },
    size: {
      random: {
        enable: true,
      },
      value: {
        min: 1,
        max: 3,
      },
      animation: {
        speed: 4,
        minimumValue: 0.3,
      },
    },
  },
};
export default particlesConfig;
```

**dummy data**"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change particle & background colour you need to adjust the below values respectively (with hex code colours) in your config. I also included `links` (the ones between the dots) as you can also adjust their colour

```
particles: {
  color: {
    value: "#a13f23",
  },
  links: {
    color: "#098712",
  }
}
background: {
  color: {
    value: "#121",
  }
}
```

In order to change the height of the canvas component, you have to add another field to the options object:

```
fullScreen: false
```

Once this is done, you have to target `tsparticles` id and add `height` attribute with a value that fits your needs, example below:

```
#tsparticles {
  height: 100px
}
```

Here's [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-knuth-djvwe?file=/src/App.js) to test.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time to answer the question it did work .. :) Also can tell about how to change the height?

Comment: Good to know, you can mark the question as answered then. You would have to be more specific about the height, as I am not sure which height you are referring to?

Comment: by height i mean how to change the vertical height so that it doesnt cover 100% of the screen

Comment: I've edited my answer, also edited the Sandbox, have a look