# How to change canvas style on tsParticles.js

Tags: javascript, particles.js

I'm trying to change position and dimensions of the canvas but it's set as inline code with !important added, editing style attribute is instantly changed to original styling.
There is fullscreen option but it doesn't change anything for me: [docs](https://particles.js.org/docs/classes/Options_Classes_Options.Options.html).
I've spend a lot of time trying to change it with no luck.
Simple example showing issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>tsParticles</title>
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        html,
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #212121;
        }

        #tsparticles {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="tsparticles"></div>
    <script
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tsparticles-preset-bubbles@2/tsparticles.preset.bubbles.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        (async () => {
            await loadBubblesPreset(tsParticles); // this is required only if you are not using the bundle script

            await tsParticles.load("tsparticles", {
                autoPlay: false, //works
                // FullScreen: false, //nothing changes
                FullScreen: { enable: false, zIndex: 99 }, ////nothing changes
                preset: "bubbles",
            });
        })();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

`

I've tried changing inline styling and find a way to set it in config. Version v1 was sized according to its parent. With version v2 I'm stuck and out of ideas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change color , background and height of the particle background in react-tsparticles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70625151/how-to-change-color-background-and-height-of-the-particle-background-in-react)

Answer (score 3):

The property for disabling the full screen options is `fullScreen`, not `FullScreen`. The options are case sensitive.